# the compiled code path to the location of the error is shown and not the executable path

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I searched a lot about this problem although there are many trials of other people but this problem I couldn't find or may be I am using wrong terms while searching.

I am using [this method](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html) to create an executable for my python code. Everything runs fine but when I run the code and there is an error. The path to the file where the error took place is relative to the compiled code and not the executable. I was expecting to refer paths where the files are currently in the executable but not to show the paths where the code was compiled.

> setup.py

```
build_exe_options = {
  "optimize": 0,
  "excludes": ["PyQt6"]}

pkgs = find_namespace_packages(include=["controller*", "model*", "Resources*", "view*",  "DLL*"])

setup(name='myApp',
      version='0.0',
      packages=pkgs,
      install_requires=[
            'numpy',
            "scipy"
      ],
      include_package_data=True,
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables= Executable("app.py", base=None)
```

> The Commands

```
python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install cx_freeze setuptools
pip install -e .
python setup.py build_exe
```

Is there something I am missing while creating the executable?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by trial and error. I had to add in setup.py in options

```
"replace_paths": [("*", "")]
```

The solution was shown in [enter link description here](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/blob/main/samples/sqlite/setup.py)

now I have the path to error starting by the folder of the compiled source code
Before: user/Desktop/projectFolder/..../something.py
Now: projectFolder/..../something.py

Which what I wanted exactly.